# Showing arbitrary headers in mu4e's headers view

Tags: mu4e, email

My incoming mail is spam-filtered by Rspamd on the server. Thus, every mail contains a header like this:

```
X-Spamd-Result: default: False [3.86 / 9999.00];
```

The first of those two numbers is the spam score assigned by Rspamd (ignore the second number…) I  would like for this number to be displayed as a column in the header view. I like to keep an eye on the spam scores to see if I need to readjust some of my filter rules.

I know I can basically add arbitrary functions to `mu4e-header-info-custom`. However, it seems like the function `mu4e-message-field` can only extract headers from the pre-parsed message plist. This plist does not contain the `X-Spamd-Result` header. It even looks like it does not contain a list of all headers, right? The documentation for `mu4e-message-field-raw` has an example of such a plist, and it only contains a `:body-txt`, not the full set of headers.

Is there any way of adding the spam score to the columns of the headers view?

Comment: Only a subset of headers are indexed, so what you're trying to do is not possible from mu, but I know you can query the path so I suspect you can use that to grep the score.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did more of a deep dive into the mu code than I intended. The indexing is not the problem, it's just what mu server spits out in response to the `(find …)` query. I'm preparing a patch for that.